How to render AVFrames more efficiently?
I have currently got the frame on the GPU and can render it smoothly. I have a decoding thread and a rendering thread. The decoding thread puts the decoded pointer to the GPU into a List, and the rendering thread takes it from this List, creates a shared texture and copies it.
            textureLock_.lock();
            auto temp = decoders_[index]->frameDataList_.front();
            decoders_[index]->frameDataList_.pop_front();
            textureLock_.unlock();

            ID3D11Texture2D* t_frame = temp->texture;
            int t_index = temp->index;
            ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
            t_frame->GetDevice(device.GetAddressOf());

            ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> deviceCtx;
            device->GetImmediateContext(&deviceCtx);

            ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> videoTexture;
            device->OpenSharedResource(d3ds_[index]->sharedHandle, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&videoTexture);
            deviceCtx->CopySubresourceRegion(videoTexture.Get(), 0, 0, 0, 0, t_frame, t_index, 0); //拷贝
            d3ds_[index]->RenderFrame(index);

But I found that CopySubresourceRegion consumes a lot of GPU in multi-threaded mode. At most 28 threads can be decoded and rendered at the same time. Is there any room for optimization?
I think the decoded frame is also a texture surface. Can I render this frame directly?

yeah, I want to stream video to a D3D11 texture. I now have a new idea, that is, I can make some configurations before decoding so that the decoded frame is a surface that can be shared. But now I am stuck in another dilemma. If I use two devices (one for decoding and one for rendering), texture copying cannot be avoided. Although my texture is shared, it exists on my decoding device. If a rendering device is used, it still has to be copied to its own rendering context. So maybe  can render and decode in one device?  But this may also bring new performance bottlenecks


This is about libav. Tags updated. Anyone not familiar with that library should not be commenting. 2) Second don't use D3D texture locks. Keep your textures in 2 separate thread-safe queues - one for free/unused textures (fetch in hwaccel_get_buffer2), the other is for the decoded textures. After copy to final frame return to free queue. Use Win32 critical sections. CopySubresourceRegion is the right and only way to go. This is GPU-GPU copy; should be lightning fast. No you cannot avoid the final copy as I explained in comments to your related question.


Don't use 2 devices. Where'd you get that idea? You should use two THREADS but one D3D device. Synchronize threads with Win32 critical sections.

You mean I should use one device, but two thread. One thread for decode, and annother thread get the same device to render? Actually, I have more than 30 threads to do this, so my initial thought was use two devices. So It seems like the way I use two devices slowing down the GPU? Cause 80% of GPU cost is on the API "CopySubresourceRegion"

@EmperorEto And what is "hwaccel_get_buffer2" you
mentioned? I didn't found anything about that. "2 separate thread-safe queues - one for free one for decoded texture?" Does "Free/unused textures" means I need to initialize some textures? For what and how? Could you please explain it more?

Yes I explained in the other QA you need to create a texture array. I thought you were already doing this. How are you currently obtaining decoded frames? Also I meant AVCodecContext::get_buffer2 (hwaccel_get_buffer2 is what I named my function). You need to set this to a pointer to a function that feeds the decoder allocated textures out of the available-textures queue. If you're not doing this then you're not actually using hardware acceleration, or this is happening in some part of the code you didn't write. You really need to understand the whole process.

Look you really need to pull the VLC player source code and understand it thoroughly. There's just no way to explain the entire process in a Stack Overflow post. https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html. This is literally the best reference you will ever find for how to make a player with libav and Direct3D.

30 threads?? Good god man!! Whatever gave you that idea? These are the threads you should have: (1) read from disk; (2) decoder/feeder; (3) video presentation loop; 3 threads at most (plus one for audio if using). Read thread just pulls from disk. Decoder thread feeds AVPacket's to the decoder and decodes. Presentation thread handles frame timing and when it's presentation time, pulls a decoded frame/D3D texture from the decoded queue, copies to the "screen" using CopySubresourceRegion, and returns the texture to the "available" queue. Don't use D3D locks, that's what's killing your perf.

A couple VLC source files to start looking at - d3d11_fmt.c - AllocateTextures creates the initial pool of textures. modules/codec/avcodec/video.c shows how to use get_buffer2 to feed textures to the codec.  d3d11_surface.c shows how to use CopySubresourceRegion to copy the decoded tex to the output surface. Look this is an extremely difficult thing to do and the vlc code is very confusing because it's multi-platform plain C. It could take you weeks to wrap your head around it all. But it really is the model for how to do this.

@EmperorEto The way I obtain decoded frames is by constructing a structure and put it into a list.
The structure contains a pointer to the decoded frame. I need to use thirty threads because I want to play video streams on multiple screens. So my approach is that one decoding thread corresponds to one rendering thread corresponding to one sub-window.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
